# Chrome on Linux tiny menus, toolbar and default (100%) page size

Tags: chrome, gtk3

On my Lenovo I am running Debian and XFCE and I have a quite high resolution screen but it being 15", I have to resize everything otherwise it's too small. Now on Chrome everything, tabs, search bar, menus is tiny, I tried to increase the default font size, but that does not affect the window itself, only the contents of the page.

How can I increase the UI size? (I tried GTK+ and without, no difference). Firefox is not so tiny.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch chrome with the flag `--force-device-scale-factor=n` where n is the GUI scale multiplier.

```
google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor=n
```

To make changes permanent add the flag to your chrome flags configuration file: `~/.config/chrome-flags.conf`

source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Browsers

Comment: Cool that works. For my xfce under Debian it's in ~/.local/share/applications/chrome.desktop under the field Exec=